# A question about Lorentz force

Tags: electromagnetism

According to standard electromagnetic theory, if the charge A is stationary and the charge B is moving along arbitrary trajectory then the electromagnetic force on charge A is:

\begin{equation}\vec{F}_A = q_A \left(-\nabla\phi - \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\vec{A}\right)\end{equation}

where $\phi$ and $\vec{A}$ are velocity dependent scalar and vector potentials (Lienard-Wiechert potentials), i.e.:

\begin{eqnarray}
\phi &=& \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon}\frac{q_B}{\left|\vec{r}_A-\vec{r}_B(t_r)\right|\left(1-\vec{n}_B\cdot\vec{\beta}_B\right)}
\\
\vec{A} &=& \frac{1}{4\pi}\frac{\mu\vec{v}_B q_B}{\left|\vec{r}_A-\vec{r}_B(t_r)\right|\left(1-\vec{n}_B\cdot\vec{\beta}_B\right)}
\end{eqnarray}

where $t_r$ is retarded time.
However, if the charge A is moving and charge B is stationary then according to standard electromagnetic theory the force on charge A is Coulomb's force:

\begin{equation}
\vec{F}_A = -q_A \nabla\phi = -\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon}\nabla\frac{q_A q_B}{\left|\vec{r}_A-\vec{r}_B\right|}
\end{equation}

However, to me this is not logical, the force on charge $A$ should be velocity dependent even when charge $B$ is at rest and charge $A$ is moving. My question is, is anyone aware about any papers or books in scientific literature which deal with this problem? Any ideas on this issue would be greatly appreciated, as well

Answer (score 0):

> However, to me this is not logical, the force on charge A should be velocity dependent even when charge B is at rest and charge A is moving.

You are using formulae valid under assumption that the fields are purely retarded functions of particle's motions.

Why do you think force on A "should" be velocity dependent? In general, electric force isn't velocity dependent, only   magnetic force is.

If B had some magnetic field at point where A is, then total force on A would be dependent on velocity of A.

But since you assume retarded fields and particle B stationary, its magnetic field vanishes. So the only force that is present is electrostatic force of B on A, and this being electric force acting on A, it does not depend on velocity of A.

Comment: I must contradict you on the part that electric force is not velocity dependent. There is a term $\vec{\beta}_B=\frac{\vec{v}_B}{c}$ in scalar potential $\phi$ which makes $\nabla\phi$ velocity dependent.

Comment: @gallieo1985 I meant independence of the velocity of the subject of the force. Which, seems to me, is your question about.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about electrodynamics of moving bodies, which is historically *the* problem that led Einstein to Special Relativity.

The first thing you should note is that electromagnetism in its full glory is a very complicated theory, in the sense that the field equations and the particle's motion are deeply coupled. Thus, a moving particle will in general produce a field that acts on itself. In order to simplify matters, we introduce the notion of "source", which produces the fields, and "test particles", whose fields are completelly ignored. Thus, in your first example, if A is stationary *and* a test particle, then as soon as it feels the field of the source B it will start moving, and your force-law $\vec{F}_A$ does not hold anymore. If you do not want to differentiate source and field, you should consider the equations:

$$
\frac{dp^\mu}{d\tau} = qu_\nu F^{\mu\nu}$$

and

$$ 
\partial_\mu F^{\nu\mu}=4\pi J^{\nu}
$$

at the same time. That being said, the best book I know which clarify this issue is Classical Charged Particles, by Fritz Rohrlich.

Comment: The question is not about the problem of self-interaction.

Comment: Maybe not. If so, the OP should specify who is the source, and who is the test particle. Otherwise, it is by definition a problem of self-interaction.

Comment: lets say that in first example A is nailed and kept fixed at all times and that the force detector is connected to this nail. I have different view of electromagnetics, in my own opinion both A and B are emitting disturbances (waves) at all  times regardless whether in motion or not. In my own opinion it is an interaction of the test charge with these disturbances originating from the source that creates the force on test charge. This also means that in my own view there is no self interaction. However, thanks for book suggestion

Comment: Then I do not see what troubles you. If B is held by a nail and A is moving, there is not magnetic force on A, and the force is not velocity dependent. If you want your problem to be symmetric as regarding relative velocities, you should formulate it in terms of spacetime quantities.

Comment: Here is what troubles me: if an interaction of stationary test charge with disturbances emitted from moving source creates the Lorentz force (vector potential part,actually), shouldnt an interaction of moving test charge A with disturbances emitted from stationary charge B create a force which is not Coulomb's?

Comment: No, because test particles produce no fields (by assumption). It seems to me that you are worried about the assymetry of your problem, but you are also not making it symmetric in the first place. Let´s agree that A is a test particle and B is the source, then the two situations you are describing are completelly different. Again, if you want to see the symmetry, you should not speak about three-dimensional (newtonian) quantitities, because these are not relativistic quantities.

Comment: I do not require symmetry, however I am developing the theory where I am trying to "discover" root cause of Lorentz force. To myself, the Lorentz force can be viewed assome sort of Doppler effect. And we know that Doppler effect work both ways, if the source is moving and receiver is stationary and if receiver is moving and source stationary. I know this sounds a bit whacky...but to me it makes sense. I was only wondering whether anyone was writing something about this

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're considering multiple reference frames? (I think). if A is stationary and B is moving,then you can think of this from 3 perspectives, A is stationary relative to observer frame and b has velocity v from observer frame,in this case b must only experience an electrostatic force as A is stationary,so it has NO magnetic field, and no curl electric field but the force on a from b is velocity dependant as its moving.

But... from the frame of reference of the moving particle it is ststionary and particle A is now moving. So THEN the force on B due to A should be velocty dependant as in this frame A is  actually moving. ( third frame is frame of A but thats the same as observer frame) .

I think the problem your having is when you are finding the forces acting on a charge you are switching your frame in your mind to be rest with that particle. Could be the misunderstanding but oh well.

( p.s electric field is velocity dependant as moving charge produces a curl in electric field indirectly)

Comment: I was assuming that "A" and "B" live in lab frame, so all motions are relative to the origin of this lab frame and was deliberately avoiding special relativity (and relativity in general)